# Windows firewall - what order is used?

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-firewall

I setup a 2012 server with some extra bits a few days ago. Seems that there are 17 ports open to the free world now. I want to only permit access to these ports from a specific range of IP addresses.

Tried creating a rule for remote IP to these ports but it seems that the rules for the specific apps are taking precedence. Thought about creating a 'block all' rule but if it gets applied first then nothing works. Applied second then it's meaningless.

Would rather avoid having to set IP range on every open port unless that's the only option available.

Is there another option? Or do I have to set the range on every port individually?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows Firewall doesn't go in "order" per-say unlike iptables which does. It simply searches a rule and matches it. You can have *both* an IP range and port range with your Allow rule. The default firewall settings deny any unspecified access, so the rule will effectively block the ports except from a specific IP.

Comment: Each port gets opened (by SCCM) with 'everyone/everywhere'. I tried adding a more restrictive list (in a new rule) but it was ignored.

Comment: You have to adjust the existing rule. Windows Firewall finds the most "broad" rule and applies it (so, an Allow All rule with all traffic would override individual block rules)

Comment: this article explains the order: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755191(v=ws.10).aspx